# Sequence doesn't contain element - PostApplicationStartMethod

Tags: ninject

I call this line kernel.Bind(a => a.FromAssembliesInPath(path).SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface());
This line is called after the event PostApplicationStartMethod, I add this line in the top of my class [assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PlugMvc4.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "CallMeAfterAppStart")]
I obtain an issue "Sequence contains no elements" or

[image]

I add the code on github https://github.com/alexandreba/mvcplugin and this issue is linked to the thread [NInject Load modules after the runtime is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190128/ninject-load-modules-after-the-runtime-is-done)

Comment: From what I can see in your code, The method `CallMeAfterAppStart2` must be where the exception is being raised. Split the variables `a.FromAssembliesInPath(path)` to check if it´s returning properly.

Comment: The a.FromAssembliesInPath is an interface. IFromSyntax : IFluentSyntax from the namespace Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Syntax so I don't know really which object is loaded by this call. And I can't call a.FromAssembliesInPath I don't know what is the a.